# Which algorithm or tool to use for object detection and extraction?

Tags: computer-vision

I will collect a dataset consisting of blackberries with and without defects. For this purpose, before I venture into this business I want to make sure that I can detect and extract blackberries from an image.

So I have this image

[image]

With the otsu method, morphology opening and closing I'm able to obtain a masked version of the image:
[image]

Now I want to obtain a bounding box or extract every blackberry from the image. What tool should I use? A trained neural network? Are there other non neural network technique for this purupose?

Results:Thanks to Kevin M

[image] [image]

Comment: Search the documentation of your image processing library of choice for the term "connected component labelling".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, there's a function called [`regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=regionprops#skimage.measure.regionprops) under the sci-kit learn package. You first have to use `skimage.measure.label`  on your image before inputting it into `regionprops`. The result after `regionprops` contains a list of regions and bounding box coordinates for each region in your image (after using `.bbox`).

Example (taken and edited from reginoprops documentation):

```
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)
props = regionprops(label_img)
props[0].bbox

>>> (0, 0, 102, 376)
```

`regionprops` also exists in [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), though there's some slight differences. There are many different versions of the regionprops algorithm. Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome! Since it helped, was wondering if you could select my answer as accepted? Helps in the future I believe on both our ends.